# Place condition on keySet() based on value - HashMap --> stream to ArrayList

Tags: java, collections, stream

little help please for newbie to streams.  I am trying to get the arraylist **select_values** from the grandMap whose value at index 1 equals the double **6.5**. A little lost with the script specifically attempting to save the key to a list.  Basically **select_values** should be an arraylist of Strings of size 2 containing they key themselves "ERIC" and "MARIA".  Thank you

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, List<Double>> grandMap = new HashMap<>();

        grandMap.put("ME", Arrays.asList(3.6, 6584.60));
        grandMap.put("ERIC", Arrays.asList(5.6, 6.5));
        grandMap.put("MARIA", Arrays.asList(6.97, 6.5));
        grandMap.put("GITA", Arrays.asList(5.5, 652.1));

        List<String> select_values = grandMap
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(map -> map.getValue().get(1).equals(6.5))
                .map(x -> x.getKey())
                .distinct()
                .collect(toList::new);

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see why the code you posted does not do what you expect... it returns a `List` that contains `ERIC` and `MARIA`.

Comment: You might want to actually ask a question or tell us what exact problem you're facing. "I'm a little lost" doesn't help us fill in the gaps since we don't know what gaps there are.

Comment: If you replace `toList::new` with `toList()` it [works as expected](https://ideone.com/9YnxI2).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `toList::new`, you should collect using `Collectors.toList()`:

```
    List<String> select_values = grandMap
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().get(1) == 6.5)
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Sidenote 1**: Since you are comparing `doubles`, I would use `==` instead of `equals`.

**Sidenote 2**: You can use operator `Map.Entry::getKey` instead of `entry -> entry.getKey()` for mapping.

Comment: maybe add two filters `filter(entry -> Objects.nonNull(entry.getValues())).filter(entry -> !entry.getValues().isEmpty())` before the current filter.

Comment: @Turing85  If the `Lists` may be null or `size < 2` (to avoid out of index when you `get(1)`) you can do: `.filter(entry -> Objects.nonNull(entry.getValue()) && entry.getValue().size() > 1)`

Comment: Hi Everyone- Thank you greatly.  Also sorry the salutations portion of my original intended message got cut off.  I didn't plan to start off my message with "little help please"  I greatly appreciate!  Have a great weekend!